# Background-position in Image tag

Tags: html, css, image, background, tags

I have used background-position: (0)px (0)px; many times in css along with background-image: url(.....); 
But I wonder if I can use this Css property in IMAGE tag or not. What actually I want is something like this;

`<a href="(some line page.html)" target="_blank"><img style="float: left; 
background-position: 0px 0px;" src="images/variousthumbnails.jpg" alt="Thumbnail 1"
width="100" height="98" /></a>`

"variousthumbnails.jpg" contains 9 images of width 100px and height 98px each. I want to display the first thumbnail which is at "0px 0px" in this image tag, and so on for the others.
kindly let me know, if its possible.

I can't use background-image in css.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you add a `class` or `id` to an image using which you can set a background image position.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are referring to is a method called CSS Sprites.

You use the one large image with many smaller images in it, so you only have to load the one image for all of your page's uses.

Here's a good overview of it: [CSS - using one background image with multiple images on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194724/css-using-one-background-image-with-multiple-images-on-it)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Yes, but I want to use it along the Image tag, can't use the css.

Comment: Do you have an example image I can use to do a jsfiddle with for you?