# HTML Style Icon

Tags: html, css

I saw the following type of image in many websites when I download the website and I don't have any idea about this image

Can you please explain it..

[image]

I guess those are all icons and grouped together, if I am correct how can i use it in HTML page.

Comment: 1.https://material.io/icons/

2.http://www.w3schools.com/icons/

3.http://fontawesome.io/examples/

Answer (score 1):

This is a so called sprite image. You use the same image as background image for small elements und use `background-position` to set the proper icon.

The advantage is, you only have to load one image once.

See this [article about sprite images](https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).

Comment: Please just vote to close on the [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194724/css-using-one-background-image-with-multiple-images-on-it)

Answer (score 1):

These are image sprites: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp
You use these combined images as background images - and move them to the right position.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194724/css-using-one-background-image-with-multiple-images-on-it